# Integrate google Teachable Machine with React Native Android App

Tags: android, react-native, machine-learning

I am looking for advice on integrating a hosted google teachable machine model with a react-native android app.

My model is a 'pose recognition' model, which is hosted here: https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/models/zrHzjhdr/

When trying to pass images the model, I get the following message: 
`pixels passed to tf.browser.fromPixels() must be either an HTMLVideoElement, HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, ImageData in browser, or OffscreenCanvas, ImageData in webworker or {data: Uint32Array, width: number, height: number}, but was String`

Since React Native does not have access to HTML elements, I've not been able to pass image to it.

I am trying to create a function that will go around this, based around a script taken from the teachable machine script: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@teachablemachine/image

I am now running into the following error:`Error: FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer is not implemented`

Can anyone advise me on the best way to integrate google teachable machine into a React Native app.